# Playframework [Scala]: Use public/private key pairs when working with JWTAuthenticator

Tags: scala, playframework, jwt, silhouette

I am considering adding OAuth2 with JWT authentication to a bunch of microservices written in Playframework using Scala. I would like to use JWT with RS256. I have been looking at Silhouette's `JWTAuthenticator` but it seems it does not support `RS256` out of the box.

Has anyone used JWT with `RS256` on top of Silhouette without having to write their own Authenticator? I only need the authentication and authorization of internal micro services communications.